# Sql Update - add on current value

Tags: c#, sql

Lets say i have columns in my database:

```
(database)
Value1 = 3
Value2 = 5
Value3 = 6
Value4 = 7
```

and i have 4 int:

```
int v1 = 1;
int v2 = 2;
int v3 = 3;
int v4 = 4;
```

How can i update my database so i add this int values to current db values so in final i would get

```
(database)
Value1 = 4
Value2 = 7
Value3 = 9
Value4 = 11
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: UPDATE tablename SET c1 = c1 + val1, c2 = c2 + val2, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
update table1 
   set Value1 = Value1 + @v1,
       Value2 = Value2 + @v2,
       Value3 = Value3 + @v3,
       Value4 = Value4 + @v4
```